# error connecting/querying mysql node.js and postreSQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

the mysql/node.js appears to connect then i "think" there may be a problem with the query event logic. Here's the code and error. I also have a separate/similar problem with postreSQL. I install npmed both in the same directory.

```
ryan@\Ryan:~/Desktop/node/datastores$ node MySQL
connection::connected

/home/ryan/Desktop/node/datastores/MySQL.js:20
    if (err) throw err;
                   ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/ryan/Desktop/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:135:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/ryan/Desktop/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
    at Connection.connect (/home/ryan/Desktop/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:123:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ryan/Desktop/node/datastores/MySQL.js:15:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

this is my server/mysql logic

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connectionConfig = {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'sakila'
};

var connection = mysql.createConnection( connectionConfig);

connection.connect(function(err) {
    console.log('connection::connected');
});

connection.query('SELECT * FROM actor', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;

    rows.forEach(function(row) {
        console.log(row.first_name, row.last_name);
    });
});

var actor = { first_name: 'Wil', last_name: 'Wheaton' };
connection.query('INSERT INTO actor SET ?', actor, function(err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(results);
});

connection.end(function(err) {
    console.log('connection::end');
});
```

heres postre logic

```
var pg = require('pg');

var connectionString = 'postgres://ryan@localhost/postgres';

var client = new pg.Client(connectionString);

client.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;

    client.query('SELECT NOW() AS "THE TIME"', function( err, result ) {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log(result.rows[0]);

        client.end();
    });
});
```

heres error

```
ryan@\Ryan:~/Desktop/node/datastores$ node postreSQL

/home/ryan/Desktop/node/datastores/postreSQL.js:8
    if (err) throw err;
                   ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
```

Comment: Password is empty, could that it be it? Anyway, your code is okay, it's a connection issue.

Comment: so what should i put for pw and how does password work, im a newb, just following along with a screencast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your password seems to be empty in both connections.

You need to get the connection details for the database from your devOps / SysAdmin / whoever created it.
Ask for the hostname, port, user and password, and schema name; then put those in your init object:

```
// MySQL:
var connectionConfig = {
    host: "",     // Hostname + ":" + port (no need for :port if 3360)
    user: "",     // User
    password: "", // Password
    database: ""  // Schema 
};

// PostgreSQL:
var connectionString = 'postgres://user:password@hostname:port';
```

Comment: ooooo yea i was wondering if i could just put in my name isntad of his for localhost : ), probably not. im on ubuntu btw

Comment: No sir.. Those are credentials to be obtained from the DB manager.

Comment: well how is it still letting me connect?                                connection::connected

/home/ryan/Desktop/node/datastores/MySQL.js:19
 if (err) throw err; why does it stop me @ the query and not when im trying to connect

Comment: See the PG example: line 8 is `client.connect`. That's the actual connection attempt. And that's where your credentials fail.

Comment: am i suppose to have a posteSQL and MySQL account?

Comment: Yes sir. Connection requires credentials.